# Unable to build in parallel using the Googles Gcloud Bazel builder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parallel-processing, gcloud, bazel

In GCP building bazel based stuff on a `cloudbuild.yaml`, I am using the `waitFor: ['-']` keyword to build in parallel and am using the [bazel](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/bazel)  gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel -builder. When I am trying to build multiple steps with the above builder and using the `waitFor: ['-']` This would create a parallel build. The issue is when trying this way, I get the error as shown below and the build fails, however when I remove the `waitFor: ['-']` keyword, the building occurs sequentially and the build goes through successfully. Is there any Bazel configuration I must change in the Gcloud's Bazel builder? Error is shown below while building in parallel:

```
Another command holds the client lock: 
pid=12
owner=client
cwd=/workspace

Waiting for it to complete...
Another command holds the client lock: 
pid=13
owner=client
cwd=/workspace

Waiting for it to complete...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
```

My cloudbuild.yaml looks like this below:

```
steps:

-   name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel"
    id: "Building Bazel components and Uploading the component manifest for ml_cmp_1 "
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
        - "-c"
        - |
            cmp_dir=components/train_test_split_1
            cmp_bazel_file="$cmp_dir/BUILD.bazel"
            bazel run --remote_cache=${_BAZEL_CACHE_URL} --google_default_credentials --define=PROJ_ID=${_PROJECT_ID} //$cmp_dir:container_push

    waitFor: ["-"]

-   name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel"
    id: "Building Bazel components and Uploading the component manifest for ml_cmp_2 "
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
        - "-c"
        - |
            cmp_dir=components/train_test_split_2
            cmp_bazel_file="$cmp_dir/BUILD.bazel"
            bazel run --remote_cache=${_BAZEL_CACHE_URL} --google_default_credentials --define=PROJ_ID=${_PROJECT_ID} //$cmp_dir:container_push

    waitFor: ["-"]


timeout: 86399s
logsBucket: gs://some_project_id_cloudbuild/logs
options:
  machineType: 'N1_HIGHCPU_8'
  substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'

substitutions:
    _PROJECT_ID: "some_project_id"
    _BAZEL_CACHE_URL: "https://storage.googleapis.com/some_project_id_cloudbuild/bazel-cache"
```

Comment: Cloud Build is sequential in nature, the build agent scans the file and execute the steps in the order they appear at. The waitFor is to be used to make a step wait for an other step to be executed. Can you share your Cloudbuild definition to have an idea ?

Comment: @boredabdel Thank you for reading my question. When we use the waitFor['-'] keyword after any step, that step starts immediately at the start of the build. When we use waitFor['-'][link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order) after any step, those steps start immediately and run  in parallel thus improving performance. When we used Gcloud bazel builder Bazel builder with waitFor['-'] the behavior was abnormal. You can try any bazel building step with waitFor['-'] to get an idea.

Comment: Ah yeah that's true. The doc is pretty clear https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run multiple bazel commands in parallel, they each need their own [--output_base](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--output_base) flag. That will make each build independent.

If you want them to share intermediate outputs within the same build machine, a shared [--disk_cache](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--disk_cache) is the simplest approach. You could also set up a full [remote cache](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/remote-caching.html) which would cache outputs across build machines. If you want parallel builds to deduplicate common actions fully, you'll need to set up [remote execution](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/remote-execution.html).

Comment: Thank you @BrianSilverman for the information, That was helpful and it makes sense, it looks like the steps are creating a lock on some shared file resource in WORKSPACE. WORKSPACE is accessible to each step and inside each step Bazel is trying to write into WORKSPACE. I have added the code that causes the error.

Comment: I am not passing data between steps and am not using Bazel itself to build in parallel. I am trying to use multiple gcloud Bazel builder steps to complete a container push target, these multiple steps I carry out in parallel with the ```waitfor[-]```.
I did use output_base flag    ``` bazel run --remote_cache=some_url --output_base --google_default_credentials  --define=PROJ_ID=some_proj_id//$cmp_dir:container_push ```
But strangely got this ``` ERROR: Unrecognized option: --output_base ```

Comment: `--output_base` is a startup argument, so it goes before `run`. Also, you have to give it a path. Like `bazel --output_base=step1 run --remote_cache=some_url --google_default_credentials <etc>`.

Comment: Now, The build works fine! Thank you @BrianSilverman.  However it is the same speed as the sequential build, that may be something to do with the fact that it is writing to the shared file resource across gcloud builds- WORKSPACE. Maybe I must learn how to explicitly write commands to distinguish between Bazel's workspace_file/workspace_file_contents and the gcloud WORKSPACE. Any way, thank you so much for the valuable insight!

Comment: Glad it helped! If you're not aware yet, the usual thing to do here when an answer is good is to upvote it (click the up arrow) and accept it (click the check mark).

Comment: As I was stuck with this for a while, shooting in the dark, Definitely indebted to your help,  Thanks @BrianSilverman, I am just at 10 points so it looks like I need 5 more points for the upvote to appear... I did upvote it and the prompt said my feedback has been recorded...

Comment: I think you can accept an answer without needing any reputation? Not sure though.

Comment: Yes, accepted. Thank you for letting me know.